# R - ggplot2 different columns by filtering, vertically stacked

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe (df2) with Age, Info, Target and also Info converted into one-hot-encoded columns as below.

```
library(qdapTools)
require(reshape)

mydf <- structure(list(Age = c(99L, 10L, 40L, 15L),
                       Info = c("good, bad, sad", "nice, good, happy, joy", "NULL", "okay, nice, good, wild, go"),
                       Target = c("Boy", "Girl", "Boy", "Boy")), 
                  .Names = c("Age", "Info", "Target"),
                  row.names = c(NA, 4L),
                  class = "data.frame")

df_with_ohe <- cbind(mydf, mtabulate(strsplit(mydf$Info, ", ")))

mydf
df_with_ohe

added_cols = names(df_with_ohe)[length(names(mydf))+1:length(names(df_with_ohe))]

 [1] "bad"   "go"    "good"  "happy" "joy"   "nice"  "NULL"  "okay"  "sad"   "wild"
```

And this is df2

```
  Age                       Info Target bad go good happy joy nice NULL okay sad wild
1  99             good, bad, sad    Boy   1  0    1     0   0    0    0    0   1    0
2  10     nice, good, happy, joy   Girl   0  0    1     1   1    1    0    0   0    0
3  40                       NULL    Boy   0  0    0     0   0    0    1    0   0    0
4  15 okay, nice, good, wild, go    Boy   0  1    1     0   0    1    0    1   0    1
```

I want to plot the distribution of Age for different Info types i.e. a plot for "good", for "bad" and so on. For example:

```
# considering on "good" column

df = subset(df_with_ohe, df_with_ohe[,"good"] == 1)

ggplot(df, aes(Target, Age)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: Distribution of Age versus "Good" column]

How do I facet such a plot for all  `added_cols` columns using the One-Hot-Encoded features, in a single plot? Perhaps using a Facet?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
df <- do.call(rbind, apply(mydf, 1, function(x) cbind.data.frame(Age=x[1], 
                                  Type=unlist(strsplit(x[2], split=', ')), 
                                  Target=x[3])))
df$Age <- as.integer(as.character(df$Age))
ggplot(df, aes(Target, Age)) + 
   geom_boxplot() + 
   facet_wrap(~Type, scales = 'free')
```

[image]